# Force mapped drive to ask for credential per log on session

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, network-share

On Windows Server, is there an option in Group Policy or otherwise, to map a network drive that asks for network credentials on each log on session?

The reason I want to do this is that for some uncontrollable reasons, every user has 2 user accounts in 2 different domains. The network drive has folders that can only be accessed by only one of the two domain accounts. So depending on which folder they want to access, they need to log on with the correct user.

I am getting inconsistent behaviour as to when Windows decides to prompt for credentials. So I thought I would try to force it with an option setting.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Typically it uses the current logged-on user. I'd imagine it would be quite annoying to retype credentials at each logon..

Comment: In that case, you could always set up a two-way trust between the domains so the credentials work cross-domain. An example way of doing this can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780479(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: I believe there is already 2-way trust (eliminating the need for 2 accounts) but it will still require an ACL entry for the folders, which it doesn't have at the moment. Besides, this is an uncontrollable situation, can't change anything on the remote file system. My question is also more on discovering whether this option is possible than to solve the root of the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this happening would be to write TWO small Powershell/vbscript/batch file that would do the following:

1. Delete all drive mappings or connections to the server `\\servername` (net use will show the current ones)
2. Remap the drive/share specifying the credentials for one of the user accounts

Then repeat this script for the other user account.

Then you'd have to KNOW to run the appropriate one based on the folders trying to be accessed.

But again, like NathanC points out, this is very unorthodox and a little silly.  Setting appropriate ACL entries for the share/folders so that the currently logged in user can access the ones necessary is the right way to go.

Comment: Have not tried yet, but according to what I remember, you cannot have 2 drives mapping to the same path. It will complain something along "path is already mapped"?

Comment: You can't have mappings with different credentials to the same Windows server.  Hence my step #1, you will have to delete all mappings to the server (again you can see the current mappings including non-drive letter mappings by `net use` cmd)